# why the following program is not giving proper output?

Tags: angularjs

Problem description: the following program is not giving proper output as it is showing only "Names and Age of programmars in local area " and not showing person information which ever i gave in .json file

```
> Blockquote

<!DOCTYPE html>

><html>
><head>
><script     src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
><script src="http.js"></script>
></head>
><body ng-app="myApp">
><div ng-controller="people">
><ul>
><h2>Names and Age of programmars in local area</h2>
><li ng-repeat = "person in persons">
>{{ person.Name + ' : ' + person.Age }}
></li>
></ul>
></div>
></body>
></html>
> 
>   

    >var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
    >app.controller("people", function($scope, $http) {
    >   $http.get("records.json")
    >   .success(function(response) {
    >       $scope.persons = response.records;
    >   });
    >});


enter code here


    >var myJSON = {


    >   "records": [
    >   {`
    >       "Name":"Mehul",
    >       "Age":"15"
    >   },
    >   {
    >       "Name":"Mehul",
    >       "Age":"19"
    >   },
    >   {
    >       "Name":"anil",
    >       "Age":"18"
    >   },
    >   {
    >       "Name":"pawan",
    >       "Age":"18"
    >   }

    >]};
```

Comment: Try getting rid of typo in json after first bracket.  You have {` but it should just be {

Comment: i tried with this  { though it is not giving proper output why?by mistake i added {` this symbol in the question but in actual code i used only this { brace

Comment: anyone help me with this issue?